# why some elements are unreachable without setting z-index

Tags: html, css

Sometimes some HTML elements are not reachable without setting their z-index to some +ve value. For e.g, here if I comment out the line with z-index,the image is not clickable anymore nor does the hover effect works. Can anyone tell me why is it so? If it is a silly question sorry in adv. I'm new to html & css

CSS(not working):

```
 .social-media{
    position: absolute;
    left: 750px;
    top: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.smediaimg {
    position: relative;
    top: 45px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    /*z-index: 1;*/       //hover effect not working and img is not-clickable
}

.smediaimg:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

CSS(working):

```
.social-media{
        position: absolute;
        left: 750px;
        top: 15px;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .smediaimg {
        position: relative;
        top: 45px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        margin: 10px;
        z-index: 1;       //setting z-index to +ve solves it
    }

    .smediaimg:hover{
        transform: scale(1.5);
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="social-media">
      <h4>SOCIAL MEDIA HANDLES</h4>
      <span>
        <a href="#"><img class="smediaimg" src="..\fb.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="smediaimg" src="..\insta.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="smediaimg" src="..\twitter.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="smediaimg" src="..\yt.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="smediaimg" src="..\linkedin.png"></a>
      </span>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: Here is how it looks]

Comment: could be something with your other code, as you can see in this example, the hover effect works, even though i removed z-index https://jsfiddle.net/gvhk2wdy/

Comment: It generally occurs when you use position (relative,absolute etc) as z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. and its disturb's by the positions some times and also positions itself have some z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely becasue some other element is too large or something, going of it. You can go to your console, click the "inspect element" button and hover (dont click) it over your social media images. Likely you will select another element.

With your current code, nothing is wrong, but if you inspect that other elements code, it might give you some insights. It could be something ith position absolute or something.

Answer (score 2):

z-index property is related to the layers in a page. When two elements overlap each other. In order to control what should come up and what shouldn't is control by z-index. So, in your code where you have not defined the z-index. There is some element that over-shadows the images. 
Best way to debug is the chrome developer tools. Do `ctrl + shift + I`and check that element which is overlapping the images.
`